# Why url heplers aren't working in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:suite) { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation }
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction }

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

my test

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Test if root exists", type: :request do
  describe "GET /" do
    it "visits root" do
      visit root_url
      expect(current_url).to eql(root_url)
    end
  end
end
```

When I'm trying to run this test, I receive an error

```
Failures:

  1) Test if root exists GET / visits root
     Failure/Error: visit root_url

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:761:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:175:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:241:in `optimize_routes_generation?'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:218:in `call'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
     # ./spec/features/root_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `block in run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:496:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:453:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `block in run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:604:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:338:in `call'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:443:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:338:in `call'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:607:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:453:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:496:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:627:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `map'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:623:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `block in run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `map'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `map'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1835:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # /Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # ./bin/rspec:7:in `load'
     # ./bin/rspec:7:in `<main>'
```

It happens because of `root_url`. I tried just to print out the value of `root_url` and get the same error. Have no Idea how to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybara is used with :feature specs not :request specs.  Because of that rspec-rails includes the url helpers into feature example groups - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/e8054a1cd03044f725030fe8315952cf3799a395/lib/rspec/rails/example/feature_example_group.rb#L15

Change `type: :request` to `type: :feature`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help

also I moved test to _/spec/features/_

Comment: can you run with the `--backtrace` option passed to rspec so gems aren't filtered from the backtrace and we can see where the error is actually coming from

Comment: Or - comment out the `config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!` since the error is probably coming from within rails code

Comment: Ok -- so looking at where the error really comes from - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.7.1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L761 -  you obviously don't have a default_url_options for urls set up in the testing environment

Comment: I added `config.action_mailer.default_url_options   = { host: 'localhost:3000' }` to `config/environments/test.rb` and now it works. I spend a lot of time trying to fix it, thanks so much for help!